# How i could use the below fread() like statement using ifstream?

Tags: c++

```
ifstream mfile("myfile.txt",ios::binary);
unsigned char *inBuf =(unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));
```

I want to write the statement below using ifstream but it is not working is there any alternate?

```
fread(inBuf, 1, 1, mfile);
```

Kindly someone help me.Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the istream read member function:

```
   if ( mfile.read( (char *) inBuf, 1 ) ) {
         // read OK
   }
   else {
         // handle read error
   }
```

Further information at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read

Comment: Thanks let me check

Comment: there is an error on inBuf, it is not working as parameter

Comment: Data type of *inBuf is unsigned char not char

Comment: Oops, sorry, you will need a casr. Edited answer.

Comment: any other  solution?

Comment: img.read((char*)&inBuf, 1); this one is working only not above

Comment: NOR  img.read(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&inBuf), 1); this one working